# Magento 2.3 suddenly very slow on developer mode

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, performance, developer-mode, docker

I have been developing on a magento2 docker env (warden) environment for weeks with no problems.
Development mainly on the frontend in developer mode, deactivating only the full_page, block_html and layout caches.
Normally the site loaded at an acceptable time (20-30 seconds) while clearing the entire cache it loaded in 50-60 seconds.

Suddenly the environment became extremely slow. Each page loads in about 10-15 minutes, both on frontend and on backend and the CPU usage goes to the max value (there are always at least 5-6 processes php-fpm that consume the maximum available cpu).
The browser loads 10 static files at a time (every 30 sec)

I tried to clean up all files, clear all caches and restart the static-content:deploy and di:compile but the environment continues to be extremely slow.

I have no active external modules and there are no particular errors on the logs.

Is there any particular parameter that can cause these problems?

[image]

**EDIT**: Another strange behavior is that inside the container there are about 20 php-fpm processes running and they all consume a lot of CPU. it is as if the php processes were struggling to generate static files in developer mode but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

<s>1. Increase PHP memory_limit.</s>
<s>2. bin/magento catalog:image:resize (applicable if you have images)</s>

Try `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` or `php bin/magento cache:enable`

Comment: 1. The memory limit is the maximum possible 2. No i haven't image yet.. but the problem also occurs on page there are no images..

Comment: Did you try the revised answer ?

Comment: Yes but i am on developer mode. I don't need use setup:static-content

Answer (score 0):

Do you XDebug installed and active. Sometimes you'll get what feel like a never ending response with XDebug active

Comment: xdebug isn't active